# LEFT JOIN com três tabelas dando errado

Tags: php

porque que esta consulta me está a devolver todos os elementos da tabela oferta_pro que eu quero e somente o id da tabela ofertas?

não esta pegando os elementos titulo, descricao, valor, user_of, categ, local, fav, da tabela ofertas

```
$cmd="SELECT 
ofertas.id, 
ofertas.titulo, 
ofertas.descricao,  
ofertas.valor, 
ofertas.user_of, 
ofertas.categ, 
ofertas.local, 
ofertas.fav, 

favoritos.id_oferta,

ofertas_pro.id, 
ofertas_pro.titulo, 
ofertas_pro.descricao,  
ofertas_pro.valor, 
ofertas_pro.user_of, 
ofertas_pro.categ, 
ofertas_pro.local, 
ofertas_pro.fav

FROM favoritos 

LEFT JOIN ofertas ON (ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta) 
LEFT JOIN ofertas_pro ON (ofertas_pro.id=favoritos.id_oferta)";
```

Experimentei removendo a variavel reservada "local" mas o problema continua. Das ofertas so recebo o campo id. Ele desta forma nao pega o resto dos dados
O codigo completo é este:

```
$cmd="SELECT 
    ofertas.id, 
    ofertas.titulo, 
    ofertas.descricao,  
    ofertas.valor, 
    ofertas.user_of, 
    ofertas.categ, 
    ofertas.local, 
    ofertas.fav, 

    favoritos.id_oferta,

    ofertas_pro.id, 
    ofertas_pro.titulo, 
    ofertas_pro.descricao,  
    ofertas_pro.valor, 
    ofertas_pro.user_of, 
    ofertas_pro.categ, 
    ofertas_pro.local, 
    ofertas_pro.fav

    FROM favoritos 

    LEFT JOIN ofertas ON (ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta) 
    LEFT JOIN ofertas_pro ON (ofertas_pro.id=favoritos.id_oferta)";
    //ORDER BY f.id_user='$login_session'";*/???



        $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
        $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);

    //exibe os produtos 
            echo "<table style= width:auto>";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>ID</th>";
            echo "<th>Empresa</th>";
            echo "<th>Categoria</th>";
            echo "<th>Serviço</th>";
            echo "<th>Descrição</th>";
            echo "<th>Pagamento</th>";
            echo "<th>Distrito</th>";
            echo "<th>Ações</th>";
            echo "<th>Avaliar</th>";
            echo "<th>Total</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {


            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$produto['id_oferta']."</td>";
            echo "<td>autor:".$produto['user_of'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$produto['categ'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$produto['titulo'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$produto['descricao'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$produto['valor'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$produto['local'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=aceita.php?id=".$produto['id'].">Aceitar</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a  href=fav.php?id=".$produto['id']."><img src='img/fav.png' height='24' width='24'></a></td>";
            echo "<td>".$produto['fav'] . "</td>";





            echo "</tr>";

        }
            echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

Comment: É bem estranho LEFT JOIN com duas outras tabelas idênticas. Se você rodar essa consulta com INNER JOIN, que daria o mesmo resultado se é como você diz (que as linhas correspondentes nas tabelas existem), o que acontece?

Comment: Não recebo nada da bd.. =/ alguma ideia?

Comment: Teria de estar faltando o id na tabela ofertas, que existe nas outras duas (ofertas_pro e favoritos).

Comment: 12 se eu substituir as ofertas_pro por ofertas e onde estão as ofertas substituir por ofertas_pro, ele roda as ofertas e deixa as ofertas_pro.

Comment: ofertas_pro.local a palavra "local" é uma variável reservada do SQL.

Comment: Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão [Fazer pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto.

Comment: Cheguei a simular aqui as tabelas e o comando e funcionou (criei apenas a chave e mais um campo, não todos, mas seria suficiente pra pegar algum problema no SQL).

Comment: Em que banco de dados é isso? Usei o MySQL pra testar.

Comment: Recomendo substituir mysql_* por mysqli_*, pois em breve será descontinuado.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque os campos têm o mesmo nome, digo isto assim à primeira vista. Experimenta atribuir nomes aos campos que têm nomes iguais, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
ofertas.id AS oferta_id, 
ofertas.titulo AS oferta_titulo, 
ofertas.descricao AS oferta_descricao,  
ofertas.valor AS oferta_valor, 
ofertas.user_of AS oferta_user_of, 
ofertas.categ AS oferta_categ, 
ofertas.local AS oferta_local, 
ofertas.fav AS oferta_fav, 

favoritos.id_oferta,

ofertas_pro.id AS oferta_pro_id, 
ofertas_pro.titulo AS oferta_pro_titulo, 
ofertas_pro.descricao AS oferta_pro_descricao,  
ofertas_pro.valor AS oferta_pro_valor, 
ofertas_pro.user_of AS oferta_pro_user_of, 
ofertas_pro.categ AS oferta_pro_categ, 
ofertas_pro.local AS oferta_pro_local, 
ofertas_pro.fav AS oferta_pro_fav

FROM favoritos 

LEFT JOIN ofertas ON (ofertas.id=favoritos.id_oferta) 
LEFT JOIN ofertas_pro ON (ofertas_pro.id=favoritos.id_oferta)
```

Ainda que isto me pareça ser a solução correcta para o problema, **aconselho vivamente a mudar a estrutura da tabela** visto que isto me parece muito errado. O normal seria ter a tabela `ofertas` com um campo `ofertas.is_pro` que se tivesse o valor `1` seria uma oferta pro, se tivesse o valor `0` seria uma oferta normal.

Answer (score -1):

Experimenta isso, e veja se funciona, eu não testei, cola a estrutura das tabelas para que eu possa testar aqui:

```
SELECT TOTAL.* FROM (
SELECT  ofertas.id, 
        ofertas.titulo, 
        ofertas.descricao,  
        ofertas.valor, 
        ofertas.user_of, 
        ofertas.categ, 
        ofertas.local_of, 
        ofertas.fav
  FROM ofertas
UNION ALL
SELECT ofertas_pro.id, 
ofertas_pro.titulo, 
ofertas_pro.descricao,  
ofertas_pro.valor, 
ofertas_pro.user_of, 
ofertas_pro.categ, 
ofertas_pro.local_of, 
ofertas_pro.fav
  FROM ofertas_pro 
  WHERE ofertas_pro.id IN (SELECT ofertas_pro.id from ofertas,
                           SELECT favoritos.id_oferta from favoritos) 
) TOTAL
;
```

Comment: Não sei porque negativou, mas como disse, coloque a estrutura das tabelas, que talvez eu possa te ajudar.